# Confidence interval in linear regression with two steps

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, error

I have a two steps model that works as follows:
-first predict the values of a series A with some other explanatory variables **X** using a linear regression. This gives me a confidence interval on the expected values of A 
-second, use the forecast values of A to predict another series B through another linear regression. This other model gives me a confidence interval on the expected values of B based on A

Now the question is: how do I combine the confidence intervals of step 1 and step 2 to get the true confidence interval of B ?